# meaning of "attract this fee"

Tags: meaning-in-context

From rental agreement.

> New Zealand Motorhomes absorbs the Credit Card/Debit Card Merchant Fee
>   (2.29%) on any deposits we take to secure the hire. Final/Full
>   Payments **attract** this fee.

What does "attract" mean in this context?

Comment: Fee is charged when payment is made in full.

Answer (score 1):

When something "attracts a fee" it means the fee is payable on that thing.

In this case, if you pay the entire amount (or balance after deposit) with a card, you will have to pay the Merchant fee. On a deposit you won't.

Comment: True, but ELU answers should be accompanied by supporting references.